# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate - One bad insert fails entire batch

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batchUpdate to insert a batch to an Oracle 11g database.

I build up my parameter array, and pass it along with my sql to the batchUpdate method like so:

`namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(UPDATE_SQL, parameterArray);`

This works great.

However, if there is even a single bad record in the batch, the whole batch update fails.

Is this behaviour configurable? I would like the valid records to insert, and the invalid records to be handled by catching an exception.

Colloquially, I had heard that if this was supported by your db, you should be able to do it, but I can't see any flags to turn it on. This may have been misinformation.

I've tried setting auto commit to true, but I think this didn't work because it would be committing the batch.

I tried to catch the SQLException, and then do a manual commit on the connection, but I haven't got that working yet.

So really I'm trying to find out if what I'm trying to do is even possible? A batch update where one bad record doesn't roll-back the rest of the batch?

Comment: If you are doing batch update how you would manage that return items?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`

Check this out: [JDBC Batch Update Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924988/jdbc-batch-update-problem)